# PyQt5 destroy a program properly

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm using `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool)` to hide the application on task bar. However, I realized that even I press `x` on the right-top corner of the program, it's still running on the background ( I see it on task manager/processes). So that means the program doesn't close properly. Is this because I use `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool)` ? How can I fix this, that flag option hide program's icon but even if I press `x` to close the program, it's still running on the background.

Comment: If you don't want to remove existing window flags, you should be calling `self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags()|Qt.Tool)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, make your own quit button and connect the signal like below

```
self.xbutton = QPushButton(self)
self.xbutton.setText("Quit")
self.xbutton.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

This destroy the app properly. Also instead of `Qt.Tool` use `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

Answer (score 1):

In Qt an application will continue to run until the main event loop receives the signal to exit. In most applications this is provided when the last (or only) `QMainWindow` is destroyed (see `QApp.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed()`).

Setting the `Qt.Tool` flag on a `QMainWindow` clears the `WA_QuitOnClose` flag meaning that closing the window will no longer signal to exit the application. However, you can turn this flag back on [as described in this post on the Qt forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11713-Qt-Tool).

```
window = QMainWindow(None, Qt.Tool)
window.show() # must be called before setting Qt::WA_QuitOnClose
window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_QuitOnClose)
```

Alternatively, you could also trigger the exit manually using `QApp.quit()`.

Comment: @GLHF can you add your current code to your question it will be easier to show you

Comment: It's really long, it'll be more confusing I think. Basically I have a button for quit, but as I said it's only closing the window, process is still run at background.

Comment: It's not clear — is the 'button' for quit the normal window [x] control, or something else? If you call `QApp.quit()` the application should always exit. If it's a `QPushButton` try connecting a signal from the button to the quit method of `QApp`, e.g. `btn.pressed.connect(QApp.quit)`.